# Jquery Html Element Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML code like this,

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="post-activity">
        <i class="loading-icon"></i>
        <button onclick="ChangeColor(this);">Change Color</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comments-ch"></div>
</div>
```

When I write this Jquery code

```
function ChangeColor(element)
{
    $(element).closest(".panel-footer").find(".comments-ch").css("background-color","#CC0000")
}
```

Not working for **class = comments-ch**,
But If I write this code like this,

```
    function ChangeColor(element)
    {
        $(element).closest(".panel-footer").find(".post-activity").css("background-color","#CC0000")
    }
```

working.

Summary, first **div** under the "panel-footer" is OK, but the second/last **div** NOT OK.

How can i reach the second/last **div** element? Thanks

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wwxw2wok/. Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: It should definitely be working. Perhaps something is wrong with the HTML structure? `clas=` or some other typo?

Comment: Does the `<div class="comments-ch"></div>` have any contents or styles to give it dimensions? Being empty, it can be `0px` tall, allowing the script to succeed but the effects may just not be easily seen.

Comment: Yeah, this div have a also `style="display:none"` code.

Comment: If it's `display:none`, you'll need to `.show()` it after setting the css. or slideDown, or fadeIn or whatever.

Comment: I check the console, there is no error also :(

Comment: @aynakolik There may not be any actual errors because the script is probably "working" -- the element has a `background-color` style applied to it. It just isn't accomplishing the visible result it seems you would like -- that color can be seen. And, that would be because the `background-color` of an element can only be seen if the element itself can be seen, and `display: none` makes it invisible. You'll have to alter both styles together -- such as with `.css("background-color","#CC0000").show()` like iabw mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.show()` after setting the CSS:

```
function ChangeColor(element) {
    $(element).closest(".panel-footer").find(".comments-ch").css("background-color", "#CC0000").show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a class selector, make sure you specify a period in front.

For example, in:

```
$(element).closest(".panel-footer").find("comments-ch").css("background-color","#CC0000")
```

Change from `find("comments-ch")` to `find(".comments-ch")`